# Expand Rect by 100px

Tags: opencv

I use OpenCV 2.4.4 in C++ and have Rect I want to make bigger by x pixels. OpenCV documentation provides [nice example](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) (look for "expanding or shrinking rectangle by a certain amount") how to use this in image http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/_images/math/a6f41031fb2ccaa600520bcbde63a8a9fcff9edf.png

Cool. Only problem I do not know how to enter this in actual C++ code. I tried:

Rect rect=oldrect+-10;
Rect rect=oldrect-+10;
and 
Rect rect=oldrect±10; (I copied this symbol from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign to be sure.

I get ugly errors on any of them.

Can someone please explain, what is that clever symbol I should use and was impossible to include inside HTML, so it is embedded as image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the mathematical notation for "+=" in C++. You don't actually use ± directly. For example:

```
//make a rectangle that's 10x10 and centered at (0, 0)
cv::Rect rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
std::cout << "Original Rectangle: " << rect.area() << std::endl;

//manual addition to rectangle dimensions -- this will make bigger_rect be 20x20
cv::Rect bigger_rect = rect;
bigger_rect.height += 10;
bigger_rect.width += 10;
std::cout << "Bigger Rectangle: " << bigger_rect.area() << std::endl;

//other method of adding to a rectangle's area -- this will increase rect to be 20x20        
rect += cv::Size(10, 10);
std::cout << rect.area() << std::endl;
```

So to do your example of adding 10 to the height and width of a rectangle, think of the `±` symbol as being equivalent to `+= cv::Size(width, height)`

Well, you more or less had the right idea...

EDIT: In regards to your comment, I should elaborate:
rect += point, rect -= point, rect += size, rect -= size are 4 distinct operations, such that:

`rect += point` and `rect -= point`: shifts the rectangle by point, where point refers to a `cv::Point` object, i.e. you can declare a point as:
`cv::Point pt(5, 5);`, then if you do `rect += pt`, it'll shift the rectangle's x and y members (by default, these refer to the rectangle's upper left coordinate) by 5 -- e.g. it's equivalent to doing `rect.x += 5` and `rect.y += 5`. The case for `rect -= point` is the same, albeit for subtraction rather than addition (so `rect.x -= 5` and `rect.y -= 5`).

`rect += size` and `rect -= size` will change the rectangle's size as opposed to it's coordinate position, such that `+=` will increase the rectangle area and `-=` will decrease it.

Comment: Manual says: rect += point, rect -= point, rect += size, rect -= size (augmenting operations).
I can test your code after a hour maybe.

Comment: I need time but I surely accept or comment why not when recovered from brain damage from half day meeting I just finished.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel sounds like a bad meeting.... take your time and feel free to ask if you need clarification

Comment: For engineer "meeting with CEO of customer" is killing any brain activity. Anyway seems no-one answers this question more. I actually still think manual is confusing. There is a "rect += point, rect -= point, rect += size, rect -= size (augmenting operations)" and then on separate line is plus-minus and words "expanding or shrinking rectangle by a certain amount". I understood that with += I can move rectangle in space and with some other clever operator I can enlarge it easily. I had one more expectation which I understood later was just fool idea. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking to expand the `Rect` while keeping the same origin (just increase its `width` and `height`), you can use:

```
cv::Size inflationSize(20, 20);
myRect += inflationSize;
```

Which would add +20 to both `width` and `height`. If you also want to offset the `x` and `y` points and actually inflate the rect from all sides, you can do the following:

```
constexpr int inflation = 20;
myRect += cv::Point(-inflation/2, -inflation/2);
myRect += cv::Size(inflation, inflation);
```

`cv::Rect` has the `+` (and other) operators overloaded such that if it's a `cv::Point` it will adjust the origin, and if it's a `cv::Size` it will adjust `width` and `height`.

Comment: I think the `inflationPoint` should be (-10, -10), this way you get 10 pixels in each direction.